# How do I make a user's core user contact form visible as a block on the sidebar of content they created?

Tags: 8

On my site, authenticated users with role Job Seeker have a permission to create content of the content type resume. Resume's are displayed in a view block. Said block has NO role restriction. I want a different type of authenticated user, Employer, to be able to see the user contact form for the user who created the resume content on the sidebar of the resume's content page.

This would allow for a contact method between Employers and Job Seekers where the Job Seeker's contact info is not revealed to the public.